# Vuetify: external page CSS breaks Vuetify's component style

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Created a Vue widget with Vuitify components. In development mode everything worked fine. 
But when the widget inserted on the site page, the page CSS breaks Vuetify's component style.

For exmple? Vuetify datepicker:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BRIF.jpg)

I tried to use scoped style "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" it, but it did not help.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
</script>
<style scoped src="vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">
</style>
```

How to make external CSS not overwrite Vuetify component style?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to `Vue.use(Vuetify)`
Like there https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/getting-started/quick-start/
I mean problem is your way to include style.

Comment: I use next code ''''import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')'''  but not working