# Vuetify build as Web component style not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, web-component

I am building an app using Vue and Vuetify with Web component; when I added Vuetify as a web component, the CSS style Vuetify has disappeared. I tried adding to the demo.html file the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css">` but this did not help. My repo is [vuetify as web component](https://github.com/1shaked/vuetufy-wc).
I have in my vue.config.js `transpileDependencies: [ 'vuetify' ]` but this did not help also.
I need to note the Vuetify styles not working.
I tried the following pages.

1. [v-aoutocomplete not working with wc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66898569/vuetify-v-autocomplete-not-working-once-builded-as-a-vue-web-component)
2. [Vuetify: external page CSS breaks Vuetify's component style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790707/vuetify-external-page-css-breaks-vuetifys-component-style)
3. [Custom Web Component image not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207767/custom-web-component-image-not-showing)

In my repo, you can see in the readme.MD file steps and reproduces and the option I tried.
I Will be happy to hear how to include the vuetify styles in WC

Comment: Try to add `import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'` into `plugins/vuetify.js`.

Comment: Tried but had no luck take no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is the problem?

When `vue-cli` is building a webcomponent it ignores `main.js` and uses `entry-wc.js` instead as the official doc says: `When building a Webcomponent or Library, the entry point is not main.js, but an entry-wc.js file...`.
By default `vue-cli` already has this entry file, and it uses `src/App.vue` as the entry component which means that if you importing `vuetify` into `App.vue` all vuetify's components won't be rendered there, they will be rendered 1 level below (all your components that being imported into `App.vue`).

##### Solution 1

Remove all vuetify's components from `App.vue` and move them 1 level lower.

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld/> <!-- v-app / v-main / v-btn go inside HelloWorld -->
</template>

<script>
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  vuetify,
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>

<style> 
  @import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
</style>
```

##### Solution 2

Leave vuetify's components inside `App.vue` (remove `import vuetify...` + `<style> @Import...`).
Create a 'wrapping' component (e.g. `Wrap.vue`), import vuetify and its styles into this component, and import `App.vue`.
Add to the CLI command the new component name:

```js
...
"wcin": "vue-cli-service build --target wc --inline-vue --name my-element 'src/Wrap.vue'"
...
```

Comment: Does this work for vue 3 and vite case?

Comment: not working for v-menu and v-autocomplete